# Why toast does not work in GoogleMap

Tags: android

I tried to make toast in my activity. My activity is first inflated with GoogleMap as in

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_map_view);
}
```

Then I set up toast in the `onResume()`

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

     //---create the BroadcastReceiver when the SMS is sent---
        smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
```

But the time it is supposed to toast, i don't see the toast.
What could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: try ActivityName.this instead of getBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

Don't use getApplicationContext: Try

```
Toast.makeText(youractivity.this,"SMS Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Also try with

```
Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: when I use this I have an error of "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new BroadcastReceiver(){}, String, int)"

Comment: check my edited answer. please study the diff between basecontext, applicationcontext and this